# Why is my log printing so many weird characters and messing up the function's output?

Tags: xcode, swift, keyboard

I have a function that returns the last word typed on a third party keyboard:

```
var lastWordTyped: String? {
    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as! UITextDocumentProxy
    if let documentContext = proxy.documentContextBeforeInput as NSString? {
        let length = documentContext.length
        if length > 0 && NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().characterIsMember(documentContext.characterAtIndex(length - 1)) {
            let components = documentContext.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet) as! [String]
            println(components)
            return components[components.endIndex - 1]
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

For some reason although the function works normally and returns the correct output, I looked at the output in the log by chance and discovered that it was butchering the output and outputting it many times (as seen in the picture below).

Would this cause the memory usage of my keyboard to increase? Does it slow it down?

How can I fix this?

**Edit 1**: This error is not reproducible when using the simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`println` is not synchronized, so if there are multiple threads calling your code, their output can overlap.

I'd suggest replacing `println(components)` with `NSLog(components)` to get a better view on what's actually going on.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I had never come across this